# How could I display Photo Spheres (with an easy Intent)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I will display Photo Spheres (3D Images in Android 4.2)!

I have read http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html. But I couldn't use it. I have the following intent in my app:

```
if (url.contains(".jpg")) {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
} else { ...
```

So the image is also shown on device with Android <4.2. But on Android >=4.2 the image is shown but I could not activate the photo sphere view!

How could I modify the intent? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To display a Photo Sphere on Android you can use the PanoramaClient API found in Google Play Services. The documentation is here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/panorama/PanoramaClient.html

You can check out our blogpost from last year to see an example on how to use it:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html

Comment: The example is very short :/ Why couldn't I use an easy intent?